# Counting occurence of number in list upon user input

Tags: python, list, loops, infinite-loop

I'm trying to count the number of occurrence of a number in a list. So basically, i have a list:

```
lst = [23,23,25,26,23]
```

and the program will first prompt the user to choose a number from the list.

```
"Enter target number: "
```

and for example, if the target is 23, then it will print out how many times 23 occur in the list.

```
output = 3 #since there are three 23s in the list
```

Here's what I've tried and it resulted in an infinite loop:

```
lst = [23,23,24,25,23]
count = 0
i = 0

prompt= int(input("Enter target: "))
while i< len(lst)-1:
    if prompt == lst[i]:
        count+=1
        print(count)
    else:
        print("The target does not exist in the list")
```

I'm not supposed to use any library so i would really appreciate if anyone could help me out by pointing out the fault in the code i written. Also, i would prefer the usage of 'while loop' in this as I'm practicing using while loops which i understand the least.

Comment: You need an `i += 1` somewhere. `i` is always `0` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should print after loops over, not every single loop

```
lst = [23,23,24,25,23]
count = 0
i = 0

prompt= int(input("Enter target: "))
while i< len(lst):
    if prompt == lst[i]:
        count+=1
    i+=1

if count>0:
    print(count)
else:
    print("The target does not exist in the list")
```

Comment: This code is close to correct, but the loop condition should be `i < len(lst)`.

Comment: Wonjiin Kim nice attempt to answer the question! However, the condition in the while loop will **skip** the last element of the list. :/ See my answer for the correct condition!

Comment: yes you guys are right! i copied codes from the question and did not notice that. I edited now, thanks!

Comment: @WonjinKim you are welcome, with the fix from my answer you got the accepted mark! Congrats. Thanks for the upvote. =)

Answer (score 2):

`i` is 0 *always*, which results in an infinite loop. Consider increasing`i` by 1 at the end of your loop.

Moreover you need to go until the end of the list, so the while loop condition should be:

```
while i < len(lst):
```

---

Putting everything together should give this:

```
while i< len(lst)a:
    if prompt == lst[i]:
        count+=1
        print(count)
    else:
        print("The target does not exist in the list")
    i += 1
```

which outputs:

```
Enter target:  23
1
2
The target does not exist in the list
The target does not exist in the list
3
```

---

By the way here is what a more pythonic implementation would look like:

```
lst = [23,23,24,25,23]
count = 0

target = int(input("Enter target: "))
for number in lst:
  if number == target:
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Output:

```
Enter target:  23
3
```

Or if you want to use a build-in function, you could try:

```
print(lst.count(target))
```

as smarx pointed out.

Comment: Even more Pythonic, perhaps, would be `print(lst.count(target))`?

Comment: @smarx absolutely! I edited my answer. However, I did leave my initial approach, since it's a bit tutoring IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` for this task :

```
lst = [23,23,24,25,23]

prompt= int(input("Enter target: "))
cnt = lst.count(prompt)
# print(cnt)
if cnt:
  print(cnt)
else:
  print("The target does not exist in the list")
```

**Output :**

```
Enter target: 23
3
```

---

```
Enter target: 3
The target does not exist in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which aims at performing what you desire. For example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> lst = [23,23,25,26,23]
>>> my_counter = Counter(lst)
#              v element for which you want to know the count
>>> my_counter[23]
3
```

As mentioned in the [official document](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> A `Counter` is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be
>   any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class
>   is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `filter` for this.

```
>>> lst = [23,23,24,25,23]
>>> prompt= int(input("Enter target: "))
Enter target: 23
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x==prompt, lst))
3

>>> prompt= int(input("Enter target: "))
Enter target: 24
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x==prompt, lst))
1
```